# Parse development and production environment

Tags: parse-platform

I just wanted to know is there any option to have two separate environment one is for production and another one for testing in parse.

I came to know that we need to create another app and import the data, from the below link
https://parse.com/questions/staging-and-production-environments.

Is this the same till now?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a clone option when clicking on the settings icon on https://www.parse.com/apps. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Does it have different client and api key

Comment: I haven't done the cloning myself. So I am not sure. Sorry I am not able to help here.

Comment: It says it will create a new app then it should be creating a new client keys i guess. Thanks for helping. Anyways your answer was correct for my question. I also went through this link http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/parse-clone-apps/439495. It suggest your answer